# How to add the listeners on the Vertical Pager in compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-pager

I want to know how can I add a similar `registerOnPageChangeCallback` in VerticalPager as we already have ViewPager2.
I want to perform some tasks when the pager is in an idle state. but the problem is that the VerticalPager block calls multiple times for the same position and can't find anything else similar to perform this task.

```
 VerticalPager(state = pagerState){    
 }
```

this block calls multiple times in the same position and I have some tasks that I have to perform a single time in this block

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by checking current page by passing indices to your pages and

```
val offset = pagerState.currentPageOffset
```

And using both in a derivedState you can trigger a function inside `LaunchedEffect`.

It would also be better a boolean for if this is current page and currentPageOffsetFraction if there is nothing else to be done with pagerState.

```
@Composable
fun MyPage(index: Int, pagerState: PagerState) {

    val currentPageOffsetFraction = pagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction


    val doSomething by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            pagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction == 0f && index == pagerState.currentPage
        }
    }


    val context = LocalContext.current


    LaunchedEffect(key1 = doSomething) {
        if (doSomething) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Page opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        Text(text = "Offset: $currentPageOffsetFraction")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you please let me know 1 more thing, I have to perform some tasks on the previous item when the item is not visible. Is there any way how can we do this?